# Kill hudson-job after time-range

Tags: time, hudson, jobs, kill

I am right now evaluating Hudson. Unfortunately I came across some problems with our test scripts. Which freezes the execution of the job.

I am running an UI-Test. This test waits for a Widget and if the Widget is not there, it keeps waiting and waiting and waiting and wai...

Now I want to run the Job every day, and if it should freeze, I want to kill it after 23 hours, so that the daily test will not be holded in the build-queue.

Is there a plugin/script/anything to do this? Basically in my thoughts there should be a script which analyses the starting time and if `now()-startTime >= 23 hours` the job should be killed/cancelled/stopped.

Thanks in advance,
Stefan

Answer (score 4):

There is a [Build Timeout plugin](http://wiki.hudson-ci.org//display/HUDSON/Build-Timeout+Plugin) for Hudson which should to what you want.